# Make shiny app modules share reactive values with each other

Tags: r, shiny, module

I'm trying to modularize a shiny app. So far it worked out smoothly, but I'm having trouble designing a system with two modules A and B, where A needs data from B and B needs data from A.

To start off, following [this tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) (Shiny version 1.5) I got this very basic self-contained example to work.

```
library(shiny)

#######################
#     FILE MODULE     #
# Load and save value #
#######################
fileModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("fileInput"), "Input"),
    downloadButton(ns("fileOutput"), "Save problem")
  )
}

fileModuleServer <- function(id, textFieldData) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      # Write observer
      output$fileOutput <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() { "myfile.dcf" },
        content = function(file) { dput(textFieldData(), file) }
      )

      # Read observers
      userFile <- reactive({
        validate(need(input$fileInput, message = FALSE))
        input$fileInput
      })

      fileContent <- reactive({
        dget(userFile()$datapath)
      })

      return(fileContent)
    }
  )
}

###############
#   MAIN UI   #
###############
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fileModuleUI("dataHandler")),
    mainPanel(textInput("mainData", label = "Type your data in here"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fileContent <- fileModuleServer("dataHandler", reactive(input$mainData))

  observe({
    updateTextInput(session, "mainData", value = fileContent())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Screenshot of Shiny app, on the left a load and save file button, on the right a textInput saying Hi There. Below the Shiny app it shows a save dialog]

With this nifty tool I can load and save one line of text from a `textInput` in a file.

Now I would like to also modularize the content inside my `mainPanel`. Let's call it `mainModule`.

While it's simple enough to build the `mainModuleUI`, the `mainModuleServer` introduces some cross-dependency issue:

- `fileModuleServer` needs to know of the textfield of `mainModuleServer` so it can save its value in a file
- `mainModuleServer` needs to know of the file content from `fileModuleServer` so it can update its text input field when a file has been loaded

The servers thus may look a little like this:

```
fileModuleServer <- function(id, textFieldData) { ... }
mainModuleServer <- function(id, fileContent) { ... }

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # what to pass as second parameter?
  fileContent <- fileModuleServer("dataHandler", ???)

  # would passing fileContent even work?
  mainModuleServer("mainPanel", fileContent)
}
```

What's a good way to work around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by introducing a `reactiveValue` in my main app. Then I pass that value to my servers and either change its value by writing `value('this is some new value')` or read its value by calling `value()`.

This may look something like this:

```
# Module A
moduleAServer <- function(id, someData) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # when clicking on load-button, just pretend to load some data
      observeEvent(input$load, {
        someData('This is the new data!')
      })

      observeEvent(input$save, {
        print(paste('Saving the following:', someData()))
      })
    }
  )
}

# Module B
moduleBServer <- function(id, someData) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # observe will be called when Module A changes the data inside someData
      observe({
        # not sure if I need this req
        req(someData)
        print(paste('some Data changed to', someData()))
      })
    }
  )
}

mainServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  someData <- reactiveVal('oh')
  chosenFile <- moduleAServer('filePanel', someData)
  inputServer <- moduleBServer('mainPanel', someData)
}
```

Comment: This also works with `reactiveValues`. The reason for it working is because when a `reactiveVal(ues)` is passed, only the reference to the object is passed, not a copy of the object. As demonstrated by [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-objects.html#reactive-values)